# How to control the file system on Android from Win7 file explorer?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-2, windows, file-system

I haven't found any good solution for managing files on my Galaxy S2 from Win7. I've tested Kies and some other software but I'd like to be able to move files, create directories etc. through file explorer in Windows. There was some talks about installing a server also but it feels like using nukes on a mosquito. Preferably a free software that I can install?

Frankly, I was expecting that a simple connection via BT would suffice in this era of Plug & Play but, apparently, in my case, it's Plug & Prey, instead...

Comment: USB mass storage? Connect the device via USB, pull down the notification shade and select mount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your USB-Cable to connect your phone to the computer. If your phone doesn't pop up as external device, you're probably missing the needed USB-Drivers for it.

Comment: I'd very much prefer to connect the device via air than a cable. Mostly because I don't have one at the moment (and purchasing one seems odd just to move some files). Besides that, it's by principle wrong direction in this wireless era to stuff our devices with a cable... Is the above solvable **without** using a physical connection (i.e. BT or Wi-Fi)? Thanks for the tips, though!

Comment: You could use [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid&hl=de) if your Device is connected to your Network. It works in your Browser, not in the Windows Explorer though...

Comment: I'll try that. I'd expected that there'd be tons of solution on mounting an Androphone to Windows File Explorer but it seems there's some kind of reluctancy towards such a solution. You either create servers or you use browser windows... Indeed strange. Thanks for the info, though. I can't upgrade your answer becuase of my low rep yet.